# Creating a module for all platforms

Tags: android, ios, react-native, flutter

I was searching for the possibility of creating a module for mobile applications for the different platforms whether it be android native or IOS native or cross platform web-based ( like ionic ) or React native and flutter

is there a possibility to integrate a modular application to any platform with a single language code?

i know we can make a single screen and integrate that however what if that is a medium scale application with navigation and so forth?

what we are trying to do is that we have an application that will be integrated to different clients running different platforms. and we would like to support all of them without having to rewrite the code for every platform. Thanks in advance!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to accomplish creating your UI and code once and having it deployable to both iOS and Android platforms then there are many options that will allow you to do that. The two most popular solutions would be React Native which has been around for quite a while, and then the rather newer but quickly growing Flutter option. Ionic also would make this possible although it is more of a hybrid approach that leverages web technologies to create the UI and app logic, and has cordova plugins to handle interacting with native features.

Which one you choose depends entirely on the necessary features, performance, and scale of your app along with the technologies you or your team are more familiar with and are outside the scope of this question. There are many comparisons of the technologies online that you can research to make your decision.

Perhaps a good place to start would be this [article](https://www.thedroidsonroids.com/blog/flutter-vs-react-native-what-to-choose-in-2020#:%7E:text=Typically%20much%20faster%20than%20native,fast%20as%20development%20with%20Flutter.&text=React%20Native%20uses%20bridge%20and,development%20with%20React%20Native%20longer.)

Comment: totally agree with you but not only do i want the code to work on both ios and android , I also want that piece of code to run on any android application regardless the source of it. since we are trying to integrate the application to existing applications which can be developed in basically anything

Comment: Trying to understand so I can be more helpful haha, by the same piece of code do you mean the logic behind it or just the implementation of it? If you want to be able to take the same code file and run in a native implementation of the app it would need to be compiled down to the native language (Java/kotlin for android).

Comment: haha :D i think the best way to describe this is explaining the use case :D 

Say you have 2 existing mobile applications one is written in android java and the other in react native . 

now you want to add something to both application's side menu which is basically a module with buttons and navigation inside without writing the implementation twice (one for android and the other for react native) so for example you would write the code once and ship it with both and it would work with both .

Comment: Due to the nature of the two different apps I don't think a solution exists that will allow that kind of behavior. The development paradigms are completely different since with React Native you are building your UI using react native components and code while with the android one all of your code is platform specific. In that scenario my recommendation would be to port the native app to react native and build your custom components in react. Over time all these components would become essentially a library you could use in multiple apps as long as you continue making new apps with react

Comment: The closest development scenario I could see that matches what you are trying to accomplish would be using Flutter since it is possible in Flutter to use platform specific implementations of logic and components within a flutter app, however exporting custom flutter components and logic into a native app would still probably be a very complicated process. Its much easier to go the other direction and use a native implementation component in a flutter app (albiet only for the platform build that component came from)